# How to sort "legend" of pie chart created in vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to sort a legend of a pie chart by the `doc_count` (the same way as the slices are sorted), but I can't find a way how to do this.

The desired order of the items in legend is:

```
c
f
e
b
a
d
```

(so sorted by doc_count)

Can someone help me, please? Thanks

[Online vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiiAuyvRoIABsAAzRwf6BaKDESIIMamgA2qAA1nAAnhEoSspsUAD6UGwMsphoYgC+CrkFEUzxZZXVtWiRTS2F6FAdFVU1dagATNH9IHmDKiNd42gAzLPzEXBLYz2oAOwbregAZjvdEwAcDQC6TSCY6kiyECds6ghZoFCpUAyCAW26GAAHIkCDUIYQQAZJCeQSGfQghRQpgQqGw+GGABCIIamQSDAQlHmN2CSAgEWQ+U8mLgghAsx+gj+AMwQJUASJlGptLh9MMAH4-Fziby4HSEQBqKGGAAUIMMMsJxPmSqhAEpFZCVSTWkoKREAfDGc0QjRZKUnF8QGwcBEIETgicbIJlBFSqMLuTKehMGxAoIAGqpdKMm5KE5PBBAzKyf6CBTxwSCO5m5mswEROXqbrKOW6z3LWoEXX+wMhtKWABUhgAjLFDLWG9ENYYCPXYm2ZYqAKQgn0RHBwdRQOC1Sm3JQA-Ijm3IdQ5JIPfLDoqj4LVdnqABKSGUNAYvumMyU46qB9kZGXVUE72XLvp7vQxvpwUwq45sjYCAtqWCFhkOOz6gK+ggAGJyJgADKNAAF5AnWjRKDIDgPq6z4qJ0ux1A0eGzAuS6oKAH5rn6cAAB51JGUGwQhaB1gArDRtQAOpwDQZBYG0bBusETwHkeaCTGIp4gOebCXtexEPJREygI+fEvvyDJKKRX4-n+DL3Le94yYpmFge+n4RN+v6yP++FmoRy7qRE7JUfx+6Hr6THRCxMHwYh6xnrIF4WtJJFyehT5DiOY4TsZZEgGZWmmiAunqMuKRVhETgwCIjJ4RG4l+ZJAW2fAiT6RhHrYd6akmegACODDPDogQ6KQwQQIEUBEY86T3O8qhJSVoXoEWOFRRytX1XQAQ0M1KHvBMKhqBFUnxf6vE6PaqDZCABlGipI2mZpFnaWa22DeVKyVdFY21BNTXbLMJ0gMOo7jpglIXRp5mWWmIDEDY1oya1uZ5GgyaCHhQA)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with embedded data.",
  "width": "600",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"key": "a", "doc_count": 4},
      {"key": "b", "doc_count": 6},
      {"key": "c", "doc_count": 20},
      {"key": "d", "doc_count": 3},
      {"key": "e", "doc_count": 7},
      {"key": "f", "doc_count": 8}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "{'a': 'Label A', 'b': 'Label B'}[datum.key]",
      "as": "maybeLabel"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.maybeLabel ? datum.maybeLabel + ' (' + datum.key + ')' : datum.key",
      "as": "label"
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "sum", "field": "doc_count", "as": "totalValue"}],
      "frame": [null, null]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "(round(datum.doc_count/datum.totalValue * 100 * 100) / 100) + ' %'",
      "as": "percents"
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "arc", "outerRadius": 200},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "label",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {"labelFontSize": 14},
          "sort": {"field": "doc_count"} // <- this does not work
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fontSize": 15,
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "radius": 240
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"},
        "color": {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 150, "fontSize": 13},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "percents", "type": "nominal"},
        "color": {"value": "white"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "doc_count", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
    "order": {
      "field": "doc_count",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "sort": "descending"
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "doc_count", "type": "quantitative"},
      {"field": "percents", "type": "nominal"}
    ]
  },
  "view": {"stroke": null}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your changes were almost correct, you just missed to add sort order in color. Also repeat the sort in other layers as well which will resolve the sorting for you.
Below is the snippet and [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiiAuyvRoIABsAAzRwf6BaKDESIIMamgA2qAA1nAAnhEoSspsUAD6UGwMsphoYgC+CrkFEUzxZZXVtWiRTS2F6FAdFVU1dagATNH9IHmDKiNd42gAzLPzEXBLYz2oAOwbregAZjvdEwAcDQC6TSCY6kiyECds6ghZoFCpUAyCAW26GAAHIkCDUIYQQAZJCeQSGfQghRQpgQqGw+GGABCIIamQSDAQlHmN2CSAgEWQ+U8mLgghAsx+gj+AMwQJUASJlGptLh9MMAH4-Fziby4HSEQBqKGGAAUIMMMsJxPmSqhAEpFZCVSTWkoKREAfDGc0QjRZKUnF8QGwcBEIETgicbIJlBFSqMLuTKehMGxAoIAGqpdKMm5KE5PBBAzKyf6CBTxwSCO5m5mswEROXqbrKOW6z3LWoEXX+wMhtKWABUhgAjLFDLWG9ENYYCPXYm2ZYqAKQgn0RHBwdRQOC1Sm3JQA-Ijm3IdQ5JIPfLDoqj4LVdnqABKSGUNAYvumMyU46qB9kZGXVUE72XLvp7vQxvpwUwq45sjYCAtqWCFhkOOz6gK+ggAGJyJgADKNAAF5AnWjRKDIDgPq6z4qJ0ux1Eo7yqOoHpqGOloWteDQUbMC5LqgoAfmufpwAAHrhIBvLUsEIWgdYAKyRlBADqcA0GQWBtGwbrBE8B5HmgkxiKeIDnmwl7XrRDzMRMoCPpJL78gySj0V+P5-gy9y3ve6k6ZhYHvp+ETfr+sj-ih7xaWxGEeth3p4eoBFEdAwFkYylFmtRy5GRE7IscEFmEegTgwCIUn7oevq8dE-EcfBiHrGesgXsF6nRe51lDiOJGYJShn2egjmmSFU5KQVKlFXR8CJFZnnoEWOF2QxIAAI4MM8OiBDopDBBAgRQDRjzpPc+Fzl1T5eV6Kw1QNw2jXQAQ0JNrloT1xFBVepoPGwEk6PaqDZB5q16Sam3GU5-6zGVPXeRtK5bSNtS7RN2zvd1IDDqO45Vf1L0Nbc9zEDY1rqdNuZ5GgyaCBRQA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with embedded data.",
  "width": "600",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"key": "a", "doc_count": 4},
      {"key": "b", "doc_count": 6},
      {"key": "c", "doc_count": 20},
      {"key": "d", "doc_count": 3},
      {"key": "e", "doc_count": 7},
      {"key": "f", "doc_count": 8}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "{'a': 'Label A', 'b': 'Label B'}[datum.key]",
      "as": "maybeLabel"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.maybeLabel ? datum.maybeLabel + ' (' + datum.key + ')' : datum.key",
      "as": "label"
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "sum", "field": "doc_count", "as": "totalValue"}],
      "frame": [null, null]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "(round(datum.doc_count/datum.totalValue * 100 * 100) / 100) + ' %'",
      "as": "percents"
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "arc", "outerRadius": 200},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "label",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {"labelFontSize": 14},
          "sort": {"field": "doc_count", "order": "descending"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fontSize": 15,
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "radius": 240
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"},
        "color": {
          "field": "label",
          "type": "nominal",
          "sort": {"field": "doc_count", "order": "descending"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "color": "white", "radius": 150, "fontSize": 13},
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "percents", "type": "nominal"}}
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "doc_count", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
    "order": {
      "field": "doc_count",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "sort": "descending"
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"},
      {"field": "doc_count", "type": "quantitative"},
      {"field": "percents", "type": "nominal"}
    ]
  },
  "view": {"stroke": null}
}
```